# Getting error referencing an object from a different class in Java

Tags: java, html, eclipse, class, object

I've been working with Java in the last few days, so I am very new to programming in Java.

I am currently going through a bunch of online tutorials and trying to learn as much as possible. In one tutorial, we are getting to learn how to use objects correctly. The person who made the video uses an online compiler, while i follow along in eclipse.

In my code I have two classes

The first is called objectDesign

```
public class objectDesign {
    public static void  main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("We are creating a new PEZ dispenser");
        PezDispenser dispenser = new PezDispenser();
        System.out.printf("The dispenser is %s", dispenser.characterName);
    }
}
```

The second is called PezDispenser

```
public class PezDispenser {

    public String characterName;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String characterName="Mario";
    }
}
```

The goal is to define the character who the object is supposed to be. I used a string called characterName and set it to Mario which i would like to return when I run the objectDesign class. I made the string public thinking that would enable the objectDesign class to find the information. However the console returns "The dispenser is null" every time I run the code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well you have two `main()`'s, and you never set the `characterName` property of `dispenser` so it will be `null` by defualt

Comment: People do make tutorials with downloadable examples. If this is how the person is coding then the tutorial is likely something I would ditch. Plenty of professionally made tutorials do exist for free.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

package com.stackoverflow;

public class ObjectDesign {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("We are creating a new PEZ dispenser");
    PezDispenser dispenser = new PezDispenser("Mario");
    System.out.printf("The dispenser is %s", dispenser.characterName);

}
```

}

package com.stackoverflow;

public class PezDispenser {

```
public  String characterName;


public PezDispenser(String characterName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.characterName=characterName;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

here are few ways of doing this

Option 1:

public class PezDispenser {

```
public String characterName = "Mario";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String characterName="Mario"; // This statement is never executed because this class's main was never invoked.
}
```

}

Option 2:

```
   public class PezDispenser {

        public String characterName;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String characterName="Mario";
        }
    }

public class objectDesign {
    public static void  main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("We are creating a new PEZ dispenser");
        PezDispenser dispenser = new PezDispenser();
        dispenser.characterName = "Mario";
        System.out.printf("The dispenser is %s", dispenser.characterName);
    }
}
```

These are not the best options, but going by what you are trying to achieve these should serve the purpose.